# BAD ACCESS exception performSelector:WithObject: method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception when I call performSelector:withObject: from a object that does implement the method I'm trying to call. Here's my code

```
SEL newSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"mySelector:withCustomObject:");
[self performSelector:newSelector withObject:myCustomObject];
```

This causes a crash. However when I do this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(mySelector:withCustomObject:) withObject:myCustomObject];
```

it works.

Any ideas on why this is happening?
PS: none of the parameters are nil.

MORE CODE:

```
// My code to call this method
SEL newSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"mySelector:withCustomObject:");
[self performSelector:newSelector withObject:self withObject:myCustomObject];

// this code is NOT called.
- (void) mySelector:(jObject *)sender withCustomObject:(jEvent *)customObject
{
    NSDictionary *handlerData = [aProperty objectAtIndex:[event positionInMethodStack]];
    NSString *newTitle = [handlerData objectForKey:@"newTitle"];
}
```

Comment: Does the message say anything specific when crashing?

Comment: No, I hit the (debug)continue button over and over and it just keeps on the same screen with the same error without crashing and logging the error in the console.

Comment: This is very likely an unrelated memory issue: the two pieces of code look identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"mySelector:withCustomObject:"` is the signature of a method with 2 arguments, such as

```
- (void)mySelector:(id)firstArgument withCustomArgument:(id)secondArgument { ... }
```

But you call `performSelector:withObject:`, which sends a message with only one argument to `mySelector`. The second argument is undefined, which probably causes the crash.

So if `mySelector` actually has 2 arguments, use `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`, otherwise fix the signature of the selector.

Comment: Ok so now I'm not getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, now I'm getting a 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' None of the parameters are nil. And my Method is not being called.

Comment: Where is an array in your code? - Can you show the `mySelector` method?

Comment: That method is plain out not being called. But here's the header - (void) mySelector:(id)sender withCustomObject:(CustomObject *)object;

Comment: Are you sure that the NSInvalidArgumentException is thrown when you call `performSelector` ?

Comment: Yes I set a breakpoint on preform selector, and when the breakpoint is reached, I hit continue and it throws a SIGBart error with the NSINvalidArgument error.

Comment: Please show your updated code where you call `performSelector` and also the `mySelector` method.

Comment: If you need my actual code, then go ahead and say so and I'll email it to you or something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15630/discussion-between-martin-r-and-manox)